# Android Studio сообщение: Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Running multiple emulators with the same AVD is an experimental feature

Tags: android

При запуске эмулятора в Android Studio, эмулятор сначала запускается, а затем зависает и перестает отвечать.

Выдается ошибка:

> Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Running multiple emulators with the same AVD is an experimental feature.

Т.е., вроде запускается несколько эмуляторов.Кто знает где и как можно отменить лишние

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно удалить файлы `.lock`:

1. **macOS** -  `.android/avd/'NAMEOFAVD.avd directory` удаляем hardware-qemu.ini.lock и `multiinstance.lock`
2. **Linux** - то же самое ([инструкция](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59682288/9363441))
3. **Windows** - `~/.android/avd/Pixel_2_API_24.avd/*.lock`

Еще одна [инструкция](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55328499/emulator-emulator-error-running-multiple-emulators-with-the-same-avd-is-an-ex)